# Typescript type issue in reducer like function

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am struggling some type error in a reducer like function (my objective is to be able to generate a form using formData from my state).

But I am struggling on how to type my form attribute because of this error in my reducer function:

```
  Index signatures are incompatible.
          Types of property 'initialValues' are incompatible.
            Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2322)
```

Code:

```
type Attribute = StringAttribute | DecimalAttribute;

enum Type {
    DECIMAL = 'decimal',
    STRING = 'string',
}

interface StringAttribute {
    isErrored: boolean;
    isMissingData: boolean;
    initialValues: string;
    values: string;
    attributeDefinition: {
        type: Type.STRING;
        helperText: string;
        label: string;
    }
}

const isStringAttribute = (attribute: Attribute): attribute is StringAttribute => attribute.attributeDefinition.type === Type.STRING;

interface DecimalAttribute {
    isErrored: boolean;
    isMissingData: boolean;
    initialValues: number;
    values: number;
    attributeDefinition: {
        type: Type.DECIMAL;
        helperText: string;
        label: string;
    }
}

const isDecimalAttribute = (attribute: Attribute): attribute is DecimalAttribute => attribute.attributeDefinition.type === Type.DECIMAL;

type Action =
| { type: 'updateStringValue', attributeIdentifier: string; value: string }
| { type: 'updateDecimalValue', attributeIdentifier: string; value: number }

interface State {
    formData: Record<string, Attribute>
}

const reducer = (state: State, action: Action): State => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'updateDecimalValue': {
            const attribute = state.formData[action.attributeIdentifier];
            if (isDecimalAttribute(attribute)) {
                return {
                    ...state,
                    formData: {
                        ...state.formData,
                        [action.attributeIdentifier]: {
                            ...state.formData[action.attributeIdentifier],
                            values: action.value
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return state;
        }
    }
}

const initialState: State = {
    formData: {
        stringAttributeIdentifier: {
            isErrored: false,
            isMissingData: false,
            values: 'String data',
            initialValues: 'String data',
            attributeDefinition: {
                type: Type.STRING,
                helperText: 'Some Helper Text',
                label: 'My Attribute Label'
            }
        },
        decimalAttributeIdentifier: {
            isErrored: false,
            isMissingData: false,
            values: 13.32,
            initialValues: 13.32,
            attributeDefinition: {
                type: Type.DECIMAL,
                helperText: 'Some Helper Text',
                label: 'My Attribute Label'
            }
        },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't get that what you're returning from each branch of the reducer WILL have the right shape for the action you want to do. You can help it along:

EDIT EDIT: You have to use the thing (`attributes`) that passed the type guard already:

```
const reducer = (state: State, action: Action): State => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'updateDecimalValue': {
      const attribute = state.formData[action.attributeIdentifier];
      if (isDecimalAttribute(attribute)) {
        return {
          ...state,
          formData: {
            ...state.formData,
            [action.attributeIdentifier]: {
              ...attribute,     // <---- THIS THING HAS PASSED THE TYPE GUARD
              values: action.value
            }
          }
        }
      }

      return state;
    }
    case "updateStringValue": {
      const attribute = state.formData[action.attributeIdentifier];
      if (isStringAttribute(attribute)) {
        return {
          ...state,
          formData: {
            ...state.formData,
            [action.attributeIdentifier]: {
              ...state.formData[action.attributeIdentifier], // <---- ERROR: THIS HASN'T
              values: action.value
            }    
          }
        }
      }
      return state;
    }
    default: throw new Error();
  }
}
```

Comment: Honestly though you may want to have `Attributes` be an interface that `DecimalAttributes` and `StringAttributes` extend, this way you can get polymorphism without reifying union types.

Comment: Ok thanks it is indeed working I thought that giving the check on the attribute type (with type guard) and having the type of the value would be enough. Didn't know I had to cast it ! Thanks for your answer !

Comment: Oops, you actually don't. Just updated my answer, but you have only typeguarded `attributes`, not `state.formData[action.attributeIdentifier]` so here it could still be either Attribute type.